# React-Dnd: drop function not firing in useDrop()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I have a ticket component which contains some data that should be transferred into another place at the database.

```js
const [{ isDragging }, dragref] = useDrag(() => ({
        type: ItemType.TICKET,
        item: {
            // data that should be transferred
        },
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
        }),
    }));
```

unfortunately the drop handler in the target component doesnt fire when I drop the item on it.

```js
const [{ isOver, canDrop }, dropref] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: ItemType.TICKET,
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isOver: monitor.isOver(),
            canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
        }),
        hover: (item, monitor) => {
             // works fine and prints the correct data
             console.log(item);
             console.log(monitor.canDrop()) // true
        },
        drop: (item) => console.log(item), // <---- doesn't work somehow
    }));
```

What I absolutely don't understand is, why the hover listener in the `useDrop` Hook works absolutely fine, but the drop listener doesn't.

First I though that some other `onDrop` or `onDragOver` listener (from when I did not used react-dnd) might interrupt it but even after deleting every single `onDragOver` and `onDrop` listener the onDrop listener doesn't fire.

Note: ofc I surrounded everything with the `DndProvider` and the `HTML5Backend`. On a whole other part of the app both hooks work just as expected. I am using `react-dnd 16.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and after spending some time testing and comparing the working parts v.s. non-working parts. I found that it was because I have `<img>` elements in those non-working parts. As long as the cursor starts with the `<img>` elements, the `drop` will never be fired. So solve this, you have to add `draggable="false"` to those `<img>` elements.

Hope it helps.